# FLEX: swfloader component not firing complete event

Tags: apache-flex

`enter code here`Been really frustrating just trying to load a swf from a swfloader in Flex and then accessing it's content. I'm sure once I figure out how to do it once then it'll be fine, but I've gone thorugh a bunch of tutorials and somethings not right. Here's my flex code:

and the as code:

public function initHeaderSwf():void
            {
                trace("INITIATIED");
                //trace(headerSwf.content['weekNo'].text = "TWRTWERWEWE");
                headerSwf.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onHeaderLoaded);

```
        }


        private function onHeaderLoaded(evt:Event):void
        {

            trace("LOAD YOU JERK! = " + headerSwf.content['weekNo'].text);

        }
```

Here's the problem:

The swf loads, there is no problem there. I see it in my compiled swf. but the complete event doesn't fire. CreationComplete will fire, and then I try, after that, to make a event listener for loading the actual swf, that doesn't fire. I've tried it a variety of different ways with no luck.

All I am trying to do is change a text field in the loaded swf.  I imagine this might be a problem with the sequence of things loading or something like that, but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When are you adding the event listener?  Is it possible you are adding the listener after the event has already fired?

Comment: Well I tried adding the event listener directly from the swfloader like this

<SWFLoader complete="onLoadComplete(event)" />

But that doesn't fire the event either.

Comment: apparently it is because I am using Embed. So it is already included in the swf and doesn't need to be loaded. ugh, can't believe that just took 4 hours to figure out.